# iMessage Pidgin plugin

Tags: messages, ichat

Is it possible to use your iMessage to contact other people on Linux, Android or Windows systems? Maybe via another XMPP client (Adium or Pidgin ...)?

What would I have to tell friends on Linux, Windows or Android so they can contact me on my iOS?

Does iMessage use XMPP, so I would have a worldwide reachable Jabber account already?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using iMessage on Linux which is outside the scope of this StackExchange site.

Comment: Edited the Question so it fits in

Comment: (i)Message is (allegedly) based upon [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

Comment: So maybe I have to install an XMPP app then that sends his messages to the same APNService?